# Error while installing Chiliprojet+redmine_git_hosting

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redmine, chiliproject

I tried to install [redmine_git_hosting Plugin](https://github.com/ericpaulbishop/redmine_git_hosting) and followed the instruction of Eric Paul Bishop.

Everything worked fine for me until step (7)

`rake db:migrate_plugins RAILS_ENV=production` threw an error:

```
rake aborted!
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:82:in `gem': You cannot specify the same gem twice with different version requirements. You specified: inifile (~> 0.4.1) and inifile (>= 0)
/var/www/chiliproject/Gemfile:110:in `eval_gemfile'
(eval):21:in `eval_gemfile'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:153:in `group'
(eval):19:in `eval_gemfile'
/var/www/chiliproject/Gemfile:108:in `glob'
/var/www/chiliproject/Gemfile:108:in `eval_gemfile'
/var/www/chiliproject/Gemfile:107:in `each'
/var/www/chiliproject/Gemfile:107:in `eval_gemfile'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:7:in `evaluate'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:18:in `build'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler.rb:144:in `definition'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler.rb:112:in `setup'
/var/www/chiliproject/config/../config/preinitializer.rb:30
/var/www/chiliproject/config/boot.rb:42:in `load'
/var/www/chiliproject/config/boot.rb:42:in `preinitialize'
/var/www/chiliproject/config/boot.rb:24:in `boot!'
/var/www/chiliproject/config/boot.rb:137
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/var/www/chiliproject/Rakefile:4
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:501:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:81:in `load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:65:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2012.02/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2012.02/bin/rake:19
</code>
```

So I opened the file chiliproject/vendor/plugins/redmine_git_hosting/Gemfile
and changed `gem "inifile",  "~>0.4.1"` to `gem "inifile",  ">=0"`
As you can think that gave me errors too...

```
rake aborted!
Bundler couldn't find some gems. Did you run `bundle install`?
/var/www/chiliproject/config/../config/preinitializer.rb:32
/var/www/chiliproject/config/boot.rb:42:in `load'
/var/www/chiliproject/config/boot.rb:42:in `preinitialize'
/var/www/chiliproject/config/boot.rb:24:in `boot!'
/var/www/chiliproject/config/boot.rb:137
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/var/www/chiliproject/Rakefile:4
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:501:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:81:in `load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:65:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2012.02/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2012.02/bin/rake:19
```

- Chiliproject: 3.1.0
- Backlogs: v0.9.26
- redmine_git_hosting: v0.4.2

So what can I do?

Comment: Have you tried running `bundle install` as advised by the latest message?

Comment: Give us the results after bundle install